# Congruence of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

Prove that $y^i \equiv y^{i \pmod 4} \pmod {y^4 + 1}$ for all $i \ge 0$. Any hints on how to solve this? I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Well... The claim is wrong in the first place...
Take e.g. the underlying field $\mathbb{Q}$. Then
$y \not\equiv y^5 \text{ mod } y^4+1$, as $y^5 \equiv -y \text{ mod } y^4 +1$.

I think you mean $y^4-1$ as your modulus. Then this is easy to verify...